# Como envia os values dentro do formData via POST?

Tags: react, post, axios, request, react-hooks

Pessoal gostaria de entender como seria o POST desses dados. Estou utilizando a dependência **"react-hooks-helper"**, Onde capturo dos os dados através de um formulário que tenho vários steps. Onde tudo fica armazenado no formData. Agraço por dicas.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o console.log(formData)

`const { firstName, lastName, email, phone, bankID, agency, accountNumber, pixAddress, cpf, cep, street, streetNumber, neighborhood, state, city, } = formData;`

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 0):

Você primeiro precisa criar o formData para armazenar os dados:

```
const myForm = new FormData()
```

Depois de instanciado, você pode extrair os pares valor/chave do seu objeto utilizando o método ***entries*** da classe ***Object***.

> O método Object.entries() retorna uma array dos próprios pares  [key, value] enumeráveis de um dado objeto, na mesma ordem dos objetos providos através do loop for...in (sendo a diferença que o for-in loop enumera também propriedades dispostas na cadeia de prototipagem - prototype chain).
> https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries

```
const formKeyValuePair = Object.entries(formObject)
```

E a partir disso pode usar um forEach para adicionar a chave e o valor ao formData utilizando o método ***append***

```
formKeyValuePair.forEach((keyValue)=> {
    myForm.append(keyValue[0],keyValue[1])
})
```

Depois disso é só enviar pro seu endpoint

```
axios.post('/endpoint', myForm)
```

Comment: Grato pela as dicas : )

Comment: Massa, não sabia que seria possível. Obrigado

Answer (score -3):

Você já tem todos os dados dentro de um objeto `formData`, agora basta você fazer sua chamada *POST* utilizando algum http client.
Exemplo com axios:

```
axios.post('/api/seu-endpoint', formData)
  .then(res => console.log(res))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Comment: Obrigado man, tinha essa dúvida sobre o que fazer com o objeto. Vlw : )